# Is there an API to add an item to the gutters context menu?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing a debugging extension which introduces a new log point type. For the best UX, I would love to provide access to the new log point the same way as vscode provides its own: Via the gutter context menu.

[image: vscode Gutter menu to manage debugging breakpoints]

Is there an official way to extend the items provided in this menu?

There is `gutterIconPath` of `DecorationRenderOptions`, which allows adding a custom icon to the gutter via a `FileDecorationProvider`. This is a visual modification only though; it does not allow to attach any interaction to the icon.

Thanks for any pointers and suggestions :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. It was released in v1.78 (April 2023) and it is called `editor/lineNumber/context menu`. More details here https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_78#_editorlinenumbercontext-menu.

You just need to contribute items to this menu and it will be displayed in the gutter, with right click. Something like:

```json
    "editor/lineNumber/context": [
        {
            "command": "_bookmarks.addBookmarkAtLine#gutter",
            "when": "editorLineNumber not in bookmarks.linesWithBookmarks",
            "group": "bookmarks"
        }
    ]
```

Hope this helps